# Wordpress Child Theme jQuery conflicts with Parent Theme's jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

---

I developed a Wordpress Child Theme in which I enqueued jQuery:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-js', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js');
```

But it's conflicting with jQuery enqueued in the parent theme.

So, I removed the above enqueue script and added dependency in my script enqueue:

```
wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_theme_file_uri('/js/scripts-bundled.js'), array('jquery'), '1.2', true);
```

But it didn't work (got the error "*$ is not a function*" in browser console). I checked the page source code and found that **parent theme's scripts are loaded after my child theme's scripts**.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach is wrong, you should not enqueue external jQuery file.

Second approach is correct, but there is a little problem there which can be fixed one of these 2 ways:

1. Replace all $ symbols to jQuery in js/scripts-bundled.js. And it will solve the problem. And this is more correct way than the way i write below.
2. Disable jQuery Noconflict mode using this script: (you can add this to functions.php of your theme)

   ```
   function disable_noconflict() {
   wp_add_inline_script( 'jquery-core', '$ = jQuery;' );
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'disable_noconflict' );
   ```

Comment: May I suggest that another approach is ideal? Instead of replacing all `$` with `jQuery`, instead wrap all jQuery in a no-conflict-safe document ready, like so: `jQuery(function($) { // ... $ is safe to use in here .... });` - I would NOT recommend disabling no-conflict mode.... WP did that for a reason!

Comment: I took #1 approach, fixed the issue. Many thanks! Why couldn't I use $?